# What Launcher app lets me put the most on one screen?

Tags: applications, launcher

I'm currently using LauncherPro which lets me have 4x5 icons and a bar at the bottom of my home screen. Are there any alternative Launcher apps that will let me cram more in?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not a launcher app itself, but [MultIcon](http://www.androidpolice.com/2010/09/06/app-of-the-week-multicon-reclaim-your-home-screen-real-estate/) (review link) lets you cram multiple icons into a teeny tiny space. Also available via [cyrket.](http://www.cyrket.com/p/android/com.h9kdroid.multicon/)

[image: that's a lotta icons]

Now, that unconfigured screnshot is the extreme example -- but the density ranges from 4 incons in the space of 1 on down. It's pretty handy -- plus it comes with its own shortcuts widgets to a few things. Can't have icons for normal folders, however. Bummer.

Answer (score 2):

Zeam ([Zeam.org](http://zeam.org/)) is a great alternative launcher that offers an 8x8 workspace on each screen (up to 7) as well as multiple dock icons.

[Zeam Is the Fastest Android Launcher We've Seen Yet](http://lifehacker.com/5729485/zeam-is-the-fastest-android-launcher-weve-seen-yet) (via Lifehacker)

Answer (score 1):

You should try the [ADW.launcher](http://www.appbrain.com/app/org.adw.launcher) , its free and lets you have up to a 8 x 8 screen plus 4 dock icons . It also allows you to resize widgets ( I reduce my clock to 1x1 and increase a few others).

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget you can use folders as well to cram lots of apps into one space, I usually keep apps in category folders, it's a nice way of being organised also!